# How to get the new array sorted if the original array was sorted and inserted some random elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I encounter a interesting algorithms: we have a sorted integer array **arr**, but someone inserted some integers (**very small number of integers**) into the arr. how to sort the new **arr**.

Right now my idea is to get all the index of the inserted integers, and store and sort them, then merge.
but the tricky part is we don't know the original array, and just have the new arr, it is not easy to find out the indexes of inserted integers.

any idea?

Comment: You might find an [adaptive sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_sort) useful, for almost sorted sequences.